# (In context of Indian parliament) what do the words "demand" and "grant" mean in the phrase "demand for grant"?

Tags: india, parliamentary-procedure, parliamentary-law

My book has explained the phrase "demand for grant" in the chapter "Indian Parliament" but i do not understand what do "demand" and "grant" mean. I tried googling them but did not find any valuable resource. What do they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Demand for Grant** is a bill (i.e. piece of proposed legislation) seeking approval for estimated expenditures for a particular department or sub-department of a large department of the national or state or territory government from the national government's general fund, each of which must be approved separately by the Lok Sabha in order to authorize that spending pursuant to Article 113 of the Constitution.

"Revenue expenditures" (which are tax breaks that would be called "tax expenditures" in U.S. public policy parlance), "capital expenditures", intergovernmental grants, loans and advances against already approved expenditures for future time periods, must have a Demand for Grant approved as well.

In this context the word "Demand" means a formal request, and "grant" means a dispersement of money by a government or charity that is not legally obligated to disperse the money in any particular amount. So, a "demand for grant" is a formal request that money be voluntarily dispersed by the government as part of its annual discretionary general fund budget.

See [here](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/definition/demands-for-grants).

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by disperse and dispersement?

Comment: "Dispersement" means a transfer of money or application of a credit against money otherwise owed. "Disperse" mean the act of making a "dispersement".

Comment: Is "dispersement" commonly used in this way? I would have thought transfers of money would be a "disbursement"...

Comment: Yes. For example, if you have a trust at the same bank where you have credit card debt and the trust pays off the credit card debt via a credit against the amount you owe the bank that would be called a dispersement even though actual money doesn't change hands.